# Meteor user login

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is the router for my shopping cart.

```
Router.route('/bag', function () {
  //FIXME: upon refresh, Meteor.user() is an empty object it seems?
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('Bag', {to: 'content'});
  } else {
    Router.go('/login');
  }
});
```

When you log in and click a link to go to "/bag", everything is rendered correctly. However, if you refresh the page when you are on "/bag" page, then it redirects me to "/login" page instead. Is there something I am missing about Meteor? Am I calling `Meteor.user()` in the wrong place?

Comment: Dis you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because `Meteor.user()` collection isn't ready yet, also did you have a loading template?

try putting this

```
waitOn:function(){
 return Meteor.subscribe('someUsercollectionPublish')
}
```

There are more options to accomplish this.

Like using the `helper currentUser` from password packages.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  <!-- show bags stuff -->
{{else}}
  {{> login}} <!-- render login Template -->
{{/if}}
```

or using the `iron:router` method `onBeforeAction`.

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.render('bag');
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'bags'});
```